# How to switch to a modal in Python using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, switch-statement

I'm using Python and Selenium. My problem is that I can't switch on the modal that pops out and I can't click the buttons in it.

This is the elements of the modal:

[image]

This is my code:

## minus the url of course

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\sasdsa\\automate\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
user_name = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='username']")
user_name.send_keys("test.employee")

##Password
pass_word = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='password']")
pass_word.send_keys("123")

##log_in = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn")
log_in = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block']")
log_in.click()

##punch
#driver.find_element_by_id("//@id='product_view')
#To open the modal
punch_in = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right']")
punch_in.click()


#cant switch to the modal to access the button
browser.switch_to_frame("product_view")
punch_in2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='save_me']")
punch_in2.click()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to switch to `div` as to `iframe`?

Comment: So what should I do?im tryin to switch from the main page to the modal...

Comment: and what should be code for it?

Comment: You definitely should not switch to `div`! Modal popup is just a common element, that you should be able to access as usually. But... if there is an `iframe` in ancestors, you should switch to it using attributes of `iframe`, but not `div`

Comment: So how can i access the elements within that modal pop?

Comment: NoSuchFrameException: no such frame>>>>this is the error that i am getting..

Comment: You get this error because `browser.switch_to_frame("product_view")` means switch to `<iframe id="product_view">...</iframe>`. Share more HTML

Comment: so what should be the right code for it? T_T

Comment: I tried accessing the elements in the modal as is but it is not firing..i mean i cant access the elements with in the modal

Comment: Right code for what? :) I don't see the whole picture, so I cannot provide you with a solution... Share more HTML code!

Comment: oh i get it now. when a form is active you will just use .submit instead of .click ^^ thank you for your time man ^^

Answer (score 1):

Delete the line below and it should work fine.

```
browser.switch_to_frame("product_view")
```

You don't need to do anything special here. A modal dialog like this is just HTML like any other HTML on the page. You access it just like you would anything else.

Having said that... if you click a button, etc. that launches the dialog, you will probably have to add a `WebDriverWait` to wait for the dialog to be visible before accessing elements inside it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Andersson and JeffC are right. I had a similar issue. I treated the modal window as something different, which didn't work by the way. At the end, I just treated it in the usual way. I simply added browser.implicitly_wait(60) after initiating the browser, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What Jeff said worked for me. I had

```
<div class="ReactModalPortal">
```

I just added sleep for 3 seconds to see if it was working. It worked.
Then I used :

```
act = ActionChains(self.driver)
act.send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()
act.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```